# How to store a network with weighted pathways?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been looking for a while and can't find any obvious solution to my problem.

I'm wondering how I would go about storing a network that has values assigned to pathways in a way that can be used for various size networks like the one below.[image]

I need to use it for path-finding algorithms but not sure where to start when storing this in a dictionary/list.

Comment: Maybe start with googling "graph data structure".

Comment: You should probably look at a graph library such as https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/ so you can create nodes and edges with weights... it also has a whole load of traversal/other algorithms you likely need...